# How to handle events in derived class which are invoked from the base class constructor?

Tags: typescript, event-handling, dom-events

I think this is more of a design question, but here goes.

I have a web application which uses Typescript.
I have a class which inherits from a base class.
The base class, within its constructors, calls some initialization code (like download .xml file(s)).
When the downloading is complete it invokes an event (e.g. Init_Completed).

Now, I need the derived class to handle this event. I know I can register this event in the base class and overload that handler method in the derived class.

However, I need the derived class to be able to register this event handler, like this:

```
this.OnLoaded += this.LoadedCompleted;
```

Here is the issue:

> How to design this properly?... because the loading is initiated in
>   the base class constructor. This means the loaded event could be
>   invoked BEFORE the derived class has a *chance* to register/listen for
>   this event.

Comment: i would suggest using an off-sides EventEmitter to handle all your events in one centralized location.

Comment: @RobG this is typescript

Comment: Change the base class so that the invoking is in an extra method (called by the constructor). Then  overwrite that method in the subclass. Add or change the eventhandler in that overridden method, then call the method of the base class(super.methodName();).

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize members in subclass before you calls the base class constructor:

```
class A{    
    constructor(){
       // register here
    }
}

class B extends A{
    b;
    constructor(){
        this.b = 123;   // Setup members here       
        super();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. But I don't think this solves the issue. The issue is that class B registers a handler (ex: super.OnLoaded.Add(this.MyLoaded);  Note that this registration process must happen AFTER the super(). Since super() will be the one to eventually invoke my OnLoaded event, class B may or may not be registered in time to handle that event. there is no guarantee class B is ready by the time class A invoked the event.

Comment: To add to my previous comment, the variable b in Class B is actually in class A (in my case). So this wont work because Class A (i.e. super)  hasn't officially been instantiated yet. Therefore that A.b is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

> How to design this properly? The loaded event could be invoked BEFORE the derived class has a change to register/listen for this event.

I'd suggest to use promises for such events that would only fire once, like the `load` event for your file(s). Promises do handle this nicely as

- they support multiple, independent handlers
- registration time does not matter - each handler is executed as soon as possible when the value is available.

You can [choose from many implementations](http://promisesaplus.com/implementations), and you get easy error handling and chaining/composition for free.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your problem correctly. It doesn't seem to me like you need an event:

Consider:

```
class Base {
    constructor() {
        init(this.afterInit.bind(this));
    }

    init(callback: Function): void {
        //Do something asynchronous
    }

    afterInit() {
         //Do something after initialization
    }
}

class Derived extends Base {

     constructor() {
         super();
     } 

     afterInit() {
         super.afterInit();
         //Do something else after initialization
    }
}
```

But if it must use events:

```
class MyEvent {

    register(handler: (sender: any) => void) {
        //Put the handler in a collection
    }

    raise() {
        //Invoke all the handlers
    }
}

class Base {

    onAfterInit = new MyEvent();

    constructor() {
        init();
    }

    init(): void {
        //Do something asynchronous
        //Then invoke the event
        this.onAfterInit.raise();
    }
}

class Derived extends Base {

     constructor() {
         super();
     } 

     init() {
         this.onAfterInit.register(sender => {
             //Do something after initialization
         })
         super.init();
    }
}
```

Just call super.init after you register the handler. Does that help?